# Can't clone public git repositories via https

Tags: git, https, git-bash

Git: v2.39.0.2

Sadly i can't clone **public** and private repos via https and i don't know why.
Cloning via http works.

I tried `git clone https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git` in my git bash with following output:

```
Cloning into 'esp-idf'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does anyone have a hint where i can start debugging the problem? I don't even have an idea where to search.

I reinstalled git but still get the same result.

Comment: It seems the https url is automatically replaced with the ssh url. Run `git config -l` and check if there is any value that contains `insteadof`.

Comment: You saved my day! I had an `insteadof` in my config from a long time ago, where i tried something.
Would you like to write it as an answer, so i can accept it? (can't do it with a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the https url is automatically replaced with the ssh url. Run `git config -l` and check if there is any value that contains `insteadof`.

You can remove or comment out the value to cancel the effect.